# Copy every n seconds

Tags: bash, sleep, background-process, cp

I have a sleep and copy function to retrieve daily output of simulations running on a cluster node. It basically looks like this:

```
sleep_and_copy() {
while true; do
sleep 85600s
copy_data
done
}
```

where `copy_data` will perform the copy. The problem is that `copy_data` takes a lot of time to execute. In other words my copy happens only every 85600s + *time to do the copy*.

Is there a way to perform the copy exactly every n seconds?

Comment: Replace `copy_data` by `copy_data &`?

Comment: Is there a bash function to time how long it takes for something to execute? Or a function that gives the current time? Just figure out how many seconds it took, subtract that from 85600s, and sleep for that.

Comment: Maybe look at cron jobs?

Comment: Btw.: Take a look at bash's special variable SECONDS: `SECONDS=0; sleep 5; echo $SECONDS`

Comment: @Cyrus I was thinking about that (bg process tag) but I was not sure. I'll try with that.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I don't think this would work since the copy can take variable time.

Comment: @Manfredo That's why I said to time how long it takes, and subtract that from the total time you want to wait for. That accounts for the amount of time it took.

Comment: I can't predict (or time) how long the copy will be (It will depend on the output of the simulations which is variable). The solution needs to be "copy time independent"

Comment: I agree with @ElmarPeise -- if you want to copy the data every 24 hours, just schedule a cronjob to run at a specific time once a day, instead of having a process running 24/7 that's actually doing nothing 99% of the time. What if that process crashes or the server needs to be rebooted?

Comment: The point is that is part of a script to submit a job with qsub. I am not sure I would be able to start a crontab on a compute node of a cluster.

Comment: Is 85600 a typo and 86400 correct value? Then I recommend a cronjob.

Comment: It is not a typo. The difference accounts indeed for the fact that `cp` takes a certain time. However this estimate is sometimes wildly inaccurate. Hence the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run your copy script every 24h (=86400s), use a cron job!  This also ensures that the task runs after a reboot.

If you really want to use a script and run it every 85600s, you can simply do the following:

```
while true; do
  sleep 85600s
  copy_data &
done
```

The `&` starts whatever `copy_data` does in a background process and returns immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is technically correct, but I'd be inclined to wait for the first copy (in case it hasn't finished) or you could get corruption:

```
while true; do
  sleep 85600s
  wait
  copy_data &
done
```